# Where is AUTHORIZE and PREVIEW button in API.AI integration panel

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to test my agent on a real device. Following instruction from 
[Official Google video](https://youtu.be/9SUAuy9OJg4?t=10m20s)

However, my panel for integrating Actions on Google doesn't look similar to the one shown in the video.
I see neither AUTHORIZE nor PREVIEW button. I can not set invocation name and TTS voice as well.

I attached my panel that I see. Is there anything missing?

**My Action on Google dialog**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That video predates recent changes in the API.AI Actions on Google screen.

The name and voice are now set in the [Actions Console](https://console.actions.google.com/), but neither are required to do testing.

If you're willing to accept the default voice for testing, you can

1. Click on the "Test" button in the screen you're referencing.
2. You can then go to the Simulator (there will be a link provided) or ask any Assistant device (such as Home) to start your action with "Talk to my test app".

Comment: Well. The reason I was looking for that PREVIEW button is because I wanted to fill my `action.json` accordingly. It is explained in chrome browser developer console -> inspect the XHR response from

Comment: Ok, your original question stated that you wanted this so you could test it on a real device. If you can update the original question with what you're actually trying to do, we might be able to help you better.

Comment: Ok. I will create another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

They launched this new platform on the Google I/O.
Now you have the invocation name and everything else in the [Actions on Google Console](https://console.actions.google.com/).

[image]

It's a pretty intuitive platform, the only annoying thing is that you need to fulfill all of the App information before testing. You can see that the simulator is in this console as well.

Whenever you modify things in API.ai, click the **UPDATE** button (the one in your print screen), then **TEST**. Then you can test in the console simulator.